# Как выложить fullStack на GitHub

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, github, github-pages

Могу ли я выложить свой fullStack pet-project на GitHub, c использованием GitHub Pages? Backend написан на node JS express, а frontend на React Мне понадобиться 2 репозитория, или http запросы вовсе не будут работать?

Comment: Нет. GH Pages это только статические файлы.

Comment: Настоящий фулл-стек не получится. Максимум - можно использовать генератор статических сайтов (например, в репозитории лежат исходники в markdown, через github actions запускает генератор (самый популярный - jekyll), который по исходникам собирает статический сайт).

Answer (score 1):

Нет. [GitHub Pages](https://docs.github.com/ru/pages/quickstart) это — только статические файлы.

Однако можно использовать генератор статических сайтов. Например, в репозитории лежат исходники в [markdown](https://docs.github.com/ru/get-started/writing-on-github/getting-started-with-writing-and-formatting-on-github/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax), через [github actions](https://github.com/features/actions) запускает генератор (самый популярный - [jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/), поддерживается github "из коробки"), который по исходникам собирает статический сайт.